# Getting weird result when trying to copy an array using slice() in VS Code

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm doing the "Chunky Monkey" practice on freeCodeCamp and I'm trying to debug the program on VS Code. But I'm getting a different result than the one I get when I try to run it on the fCC console. fCC returns the expected result for the case, the original array, but I get a different output on VS Code. Here's the code I made:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    let groupArr = arr.slice(0);   // VS Code returns [4, 5, 6, 7]
    //console.log(groupArr)
    const groupTarget = Math.ceil(arr.length / size);
    console.log(groupTarget)
    let group = 1;
    console.log(group)
    let finalArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {  // iterates though the array 'size' times 
      if (group == groupTarget) {     // if for when we are on the last array to fill
        for (let j = 0; j < size; j++)  // for to iterate size amount of times to see if there is no undefined
        {
          if (groupArr[j] == undefined) { //if there is a undefined value, we'll make a smaller array for the last group 
            finalArr.push(groupArr.splice(0, j))
            console.log(finalArr)
          }
        }
      }
      finalArr.push(groupArr.splice(0, size))  // if we are not on the last group, we just splice the original value and push it 
      console.log(finalArr)
    } 
    return finalArr; // once loops end, we return the finalArray
  }
  
  chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4);
```

Hope someone is able to help. Did I mess up something on VS Code? I only copied the exact code that I had.

Comment: VSCode has nothing to do with the output of your code, unless someone evil injects zero width spaces or something. What's the expected output and what output did you get?

Comment: And `let groupArr = arr.slice(0);` would not give you that output.

Comment: When I run it on the fCC console, I get [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] at the groupArr assignment, but on VS Code I get [4, 5, 6, 7]

Comment: So which is to blame "fCC" or "VS Code"? What is your expected output per @code?

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(groupArr))` - since browser console evaluates Objects in the console when you expand them, not when you log them - oh, wait, this isn't a browser - my bad

Comment: Neither. Neither is wrong. The difference though, is in a console, when a value is called without being printed, the console handily prints it out for you. Not on non-console situations though. Change `chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4); ` to `console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4));` and you should be good to go. By the way, are you using a Node runtime locally? Again, VSCode doesn't run code. It's not an IDE either. It's a glorified text editor that makes it easy to run code.

Comment: I'm expecting to get the copy of the array back to the variable [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]. The weird thing is that I am using the Watch function on VS Code, and the value that it shows for arr.slice(0) is indeed [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] but it changes on groupArr to [4, 5, 6, 7]

Comment: yes, because your code changes it

Comment: it's the side effect of splice at the end (splice updates the groupArr

Comment: you can get rid of this side effect by doing `finalArr.push([...groupArr].splice(0, size))`at minima